# Accessing (Receive) from IBM MQ 8 with JMS running on TomEE 1.7.4 plus

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, apache-tomee

Latest Tutorials provided by IBM for simple PRODUCE and CONSUME to IBM MQ 8/9 are pretty easy to implement.

Currently we have to figure out, how to read/receive Messages from one IBM MQ 8 Manager Queue out of an existing application.

Following setup:

- IBM MQ 8
- Applicationserver with Application running, which needs to access the MQ: TomEE 1.7.4 plus
- No WebSphere
- No JNDI

My expectation here is, that this will not work:

- IBM MQ 8 needs JMS 2.0 features to connect
- which needs Java EE 7
- while TomEE 1.7.4 plus is Java EE 6 compatible (TomEE 7.x would be Java EE 7 compatible)

I would appreciate any help especially pointing me to an IBM MQ JMS implementation deployable to TomEE 1.7.x, using straight forward parameters for host, Q-Manager, Channel, Queue, User without JNDI.

**Update#1:**
One good tutorial to create a simple consumer or producer for IBM MQ (working with 8 and 9)
https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/

**Update#2:**
As expected, integrating this with TomEE 7.x seems to work fine. Unfortunately migrating the whole infrastructure and application dependencies is not an option to resolve it this way...

Comment: The last version of mq compatible with java 6 was 7.5 which is out of support.

Comment: I guess you are asking for compatibility with the JMS Client and TomEE 1.7.4, and not MQ Sever and TomEE 1.7.4. Which Tutorials did you use for your simple PRODUCE and CONSUME samples? By the way you have described them they do seem to be a valuable resource.

Comment: @chughts I added the link with update#1

Comment: The MQ 8 server does not care what version the MQ Client (aka network attached applications) are. Using a V7.5 client to connect to a V8 queue manager is perfectly good combination. Josh is right that V7.5 is out of support, but only just (April 2018), so you could purchase a support extension from IBM as an alternative to migrating to TomEE 7.x

Comment: @MoragHughson asking a customer who is using TomEE instead of e.g. WebSphere to pay more to IBM just to not migrate now seems stupid

We now use IBM MQ classes for Java instead of JMS. It works.

Comment: @PdM I'm sorry my suggestion offended. I got the impression that migrating to TomEE 7.x was not possible and I just wanted to be sure that you were aware of another alternative that occurred to me. I am of course, not aware of your financial situation. If it was not suitable, you can just ignore it. I am glad to hear you are now good to go with Java classes. I did not suggest that because your question requested a solution using JMS. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You've kind of answered your own question in brackets, if you go up to TomEE 7.x which works with Java EE 7, you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the requested combination is not possible, we skipped JMS integration and are using **IBM MQ classes for Java**.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q118320_.htm

JMS solution is prepared and can be integrated as soon as TomEEs are migrated to 7.x.

Comment: The IBM MQ classes for Java should have the same Java 7 or higher restriction at MQ v8 and higher that IBM MQ classes for JMS have, are you stating this is not the case?  Are you sure you are using IBM MQ jar files from v8 and higher, from my experience, if you have IBM MQ classes for Java working with Java 6 those jar files must be from MQ v7.5 or lower.

Comment: @JoshMc The JMS integration of TomEE itself with Java 6 is the problem. TomEE creates no conflicts with IBM MQ classes, since this is proprietary.

Comment: Does this mean that you execute the application that uses the IBM MQ Classes for Java under a Java 7 JVM?  I he checked and all class files in the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar from 8.0.0.10 are meant for Java 7, they would not run under a Java 6 as far as I know.